# Javascript: recreating Array.from?

Tags: javascript, arrays, call, bind, getselection

I came across this code for stripping Marketo forms of their included stylesheets. Let's assume that the code author is a super senior engineer.  `Array.from()` could have been used instead of defining `arrayFrom` (functionally at any rate), so why use the latter?

For my part I'm trying to understand the `arrayFrom` definition (first line of the codeblock):

1. bind() sets `this` to the provided value, here `[].slice` (why?)
2. call() allows us to call `getSelection` with the `this` value bound by `bind`.
3. getSelection() returns a Selection object (or string in Firefox) of the selected text. This I'm unsure about.
   In its use, `arrayFrom` gets passed an array (or NodeList) of stylesheets and returns an array of the same stylesheets (a shallow copy thereof?) no differently than if `Array.from` were used, so the functional bit of `bind` and `call` must be to alter the `this` value in a desirable way. Not sure how that acts on `[].slice` though.

Anyone? I'm clearly missing something.

```
const arrayFrom = getSelection.call.bind([].slice);

// remove element styles from <form> and children
const styledEls = arrayFrom(formEl.querySelectorAll("[style]")).concat(
formEl
);

styledEls.forEach(function (el) {
     el.removeAttribute("style");
});

     
// create an array of all stylesheets in document
const styleSheets = arrayFrom(document.styleSheets);

// loop through stylesheets and check for ownerNode properties on each
styleSheets.forEach(function (ss) {
    if (
    //array of <link/> elements tied to stylesheets
    [mktoForms2BaseStyle, mktoForms2ThemeStyle].indexOf(ss.ownerNode) !=
      -1 ||
    formEl.contains(ss.ownerNode)
    ) {
      ss.disabled = true;
      } 
});
```

Comment: Can you focus your question on **one** question? Currently you are asking several "why?" and "how?" questions, making it too broad.

Comment: `Array.from` is an ES6 function. This code probably predates it.

Comment: @Barmar is right. Seems like ES5 code with `const` thrown in. It was probably very lightly refactored since it was created (probably to comply with linter rules). Doesn't really make much sense to write this otherwise.

Comment: Since it's also using ES6 features like `const` and `querySelectorAll()`, I suspect the definition of `arrayFrom()` is something he copied from an old polyfill because he didn't know about `Array.from()`.

Comment: @trincot I think he's basically just asking how that terse definition of `arrayFrom()` works, the rest is just context.

Comment: I suspect that getSelection is a homemade function.  Otherwise I would expect window.getSelection or document.getSelection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays we would just use `Array.from`. But your questions are about the construct that is used:

```
const arrayFrom = getSelection.call.bind([].slice);
```

First of all, this has nothing to do with `getSelection`, as the expression is not binding *that*, but the `call` function. This `call` function is on the `Function` prototype, so the above leads to the same result as:

```
const arrayFrom = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
```

`call` is a function that allows one to call another function with the possibility to provide a this-argument to it. Here we define that the function to be called should be `slice`. The first argument we will provide to `arrayFrom` will be like the first argument we would provide to `call`, i.e. the object on which `slice` should be called. This gives it a similar behaviour as `Array.from`.

It may help to replace `bind` by this function that does a similar thing:

```
function arrayFrom(arrayLike)  {
    return Function.prototype.call.call(Array.prototype.slice, arrayLike);
}
```

It is confusing, but we invoke `call` with `call` so that we can provide a `this` argument to it (defining the function we want to call), making the *second* argument the `this`-argument that `call` (the first one) deals with.

Comment: I see; just trying to work out how `getSelection` relates then; we are returning an array, not a `Selection` object, so what is the point of `getSelection`?

Comment: There is no point to `getSelection`. It could have been *any* array instance. `getSelection.call` is the *same* reference as `eval.call` or `parseInt.call` . Indistinguishable. All these are `Function.prototype.call`. So I have no idea why the author used `getSelection`, as it is just throwing dust in our eyes.

Comment: Got it, just a red herring. That was confusing! Thanks.

Comment: Got it sorry, new to the forum...I also don't have enough rep to upvote you :(